# Azure Front Door with Azure Signal R

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-front-door, azure-signalr

Does anyone has any experience with Azure front door used with an app service that uses azure signal r service (managed azure signal r service)
Based on my reading so far I understand that AFD doesn’t support web sockets, which looks like if you are using signal r within your app then probably that’s not yet supported. In our case we are using signal r Azure service which is external to our app service, is this supported with Azure front door?

Any answers on this are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you may be stuck at present with a Web Application Firewall and Application Gateway?

Answer (score 2):

At this moment (feb/2022) it seems that it's not supported. The recomendation is to use Application Gateway instead.

Source:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/architecture-center/issues/1891

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is supported using the Azure SignalR managed service. The WebSocket connections will go to it instead of your backend pool.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was hoping for. I read somewhere that as long as Signal R services are used, it should work. We will give it a try.

Comment: We have verified & can confirm that Azure Front Door does support the managed Signal R service provided by Azure.

Comment: If we use Azure SignalR service, the client applications will build connections to Azure Signalr Endpoint or my external api (hub) endpoint ?